# Open iPod app from within my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

Is it possible to open the iPod app from within my app? If so, how?
I don't want to go anywhere in specific in the app, I just want it to open as it normally does. What is the iPod app URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on my iPhone4 with iOS 5.0:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]];
```

Comment: also did this:
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]]) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]];

Answer (score 1):

Update:
As Bart  pointed music is the keyword and for everything else you  can refer this link for the list of all the applications you can launch and the code required to do so ... 
http://www.wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes